# Let a linear endomorphism of a vector space $V$ be different from $0$ and not a right zero divisor in $End(V)$. Then it is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question is related to this post: [Given $\operatorname{Im}(f) \subset \operatorname{ker}(x^*)$ does that imply if $ f∈End_A(M)$ is not a right divisor of zero then f is surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67549/given-operatornameimf-subset-operatornamekerx-does-that-imply-if).

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$. Consider the set $End_{k}(V)$, a ring with the usual composition of maps.

Take $f \in End_{k}(V)$ and suppose that $f \neq 0$ and that $f$ is not a right zero divisor in $End_{k}(V)$. Why is it a surjective map?

I cannot understand how to apply the linked argument. I have tried to prove that, if $f$ is not surjective, then $f$ is a right zero divisor: let $\bar{v} \in V \setminus f(V)$, then $\bar{v} \neq 0$ and I can complete it to a basis for $V$, say $\{ \bar{v}  \cup \{ w_{j} \}_{j\in J} \} := B$. Then I tried to define a linear map $g$ on this $B$, such that $gf=0$, but apparently I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I tried to define a linear map $g$ on this $B$, such that $gf=0$, but apparently I cannot do that.

The obvious choice is to define $g$ to be zero on $f(V)$ and the identity elsewhere. Then the composition is zero and g is nonzero.

Comment: Why is that $g$ linear?

Comment: @ImreMezo If you choose a basis for $f(V)$ and extend it to a basis for the whole space, you can choose the images of the basis however you like, and you are guaranteed that defines a linear transformation. That's what bases are for.